# DLL fails to load from Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll

I am running a 32-bit version of Eclipse on a 64-bit Windows 7 PC (everything involved is 32-bit).

My eclipse program calls an external C++ function, X, that calls another function, Y, which uses LoadLibrary to load several DLLs, most of which themselves reference other DLLs. All of the DLLs load except one which fails with a 193 error.

If instead I call Y directly from a stand-alone C++ program, all the DLLs load and everything works.
This tells me that there are no missing dependencies, 32-bit/64-bit issues, or corrupted files.

Using Procmon.exe I can see the correct DLLs being opened (apparently successfully), so it isn't a path issue, yet I am getting this error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `#define ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT 193L`. Watch with procmon closely, there should be some difference in traces 'cause what you try to load isn't right dll

Comment: It's a bit unclear if the difference is you're running your program from within eclipse or from shell. If sou, it might be a path issue, since eclipse doesn't necessarily use the same path as set for shell. Look in the run/debug settings, it can be set there AFAIR.

Comment: By writing "a stand-alone C++ program" I was indicating that the working case is called from the command line, not from within eclipse. Also, I did mention that it wasn't a path issue as Procmon shows the correct DLLs being opened.